# nightwatch : failure callback on waitForElementPresent

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Do you know how to add a failure callback to `waitForElementPresent`

I would like to do something like below:

```
browser.url('http://google.com')
       .waitForElementPresent('body', 10000, true, function (result) {
           browser.globals.log('I am going here just in success case'); 
       })
```

Do you know how  failure callback are working?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is aboolean that allow to set if  that test abort on failure, you have to set it to false

Then you can see if element has been seen in callback

The code bellow works

```
 browser.waitForElementVisible('#idElement', 4000, false, function (result) {
   if (result.state  && result.state == "success") 
   {
       //success
    }
    else
    {
       //failure, the element has not appear before time has been elapsed
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, what is #idElement here?? is that an xpath, id, name or what?

Comment: @mashkurm I know you can use a js selector that  you could use in function querySelector or jquery #, dont know if you ca n use a xpath